# Creating dummy by two conditions across two data frames

Tags: r

df1

```
firm  date.df1
A     2001-01-01
A     2001-05-01
B     2002-04-15
D     2001-05-12
```

df2

```
firm  date.df2
A     2001-02-01
D     2001-01-03
E     2005-08-15
V     2013-06-13
```

I want to make a dummy variable in df1: if firm x has a date.df1 that is 30 days prior to its date
in df2, then 1, else 0. Ive been thinking of many possible solutions, but neither seem to give me correctly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Make left join of df2 on df1, calculate day differences between dates and calculate flag by validating your condition on day differences:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = "firm") %>%
  mutate(
    day_diff = as.integer(as.Date(date.df2) - as.Date(date.df1)),
    flag = ifelse(between(day_diff, 0, 30), 1, 0)
  ) %>%
  select(-day_diff, -date.df2)
```

gives:

```
  firm  date.df1    flag
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
1 A     2001-01-01     0
2 A     2001-05-01     0
3 B     2002-04-15    NA
4 D     2001-05-12     0
```

Comment: I tried you code, i got the following error: 

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `flag`.
x arguments must have same length
ℹ Input `flag` is `ifelse(between(day_diff, 0, 30), 1, 0)`.